# Cómo centrar correctamente menú de listas <ul> horizontal dentro de nav con css

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Este es mi código del menú:

```html
    <nav class="nav">
   <ul>
    <li><a class="menu__link" href=" ">Ejemplo</li></a>
    <li><a class="menu__link" href=" ">Ejemplo</li></a>
    <li><a class="menu__link" href=" ">Ejemplo</li></a>
    <li><a class="menu__link" href=" ">Ejemplo</li></a>
    <li><a class="menu__link" href=" ">Ejemplo</li></a>
   </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: ¿qué has intentado para centralas?

Comment: Te recomiendo usar [Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se puede lograr con flexbox, estableciendo `<ul>` como su contenedor, fijando la dirección en columnas y centrando su eje no principal.

```css
nav > ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="menu__link" href="#">Ejemplo</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu__link" href="#">Ejemplo</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu__link" href="#">Ejemplo</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu__link" href="#">Ejemplo</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu__link" href="#">Ejemplo</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Si la idea es centrar la lista y que sus elementos estén en un layout "horizontal", es más fácil aún:

```css
nav > ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

li {
  margin: 0 .75rem;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="menu__link" href="#">Ejemplo</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu__link" href="#">Ejemplo</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu__link" href="#">Ejemplo</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu__link" href="#">Ejemplo</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu__link" href="#">Ejemplo</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: ¿Porque al poner `display: flex` se ponen directamente en horizontal?

Comment: Porque el valor por defecto de `flex-direction` es `row`.

Comment: Es verdad, se me había olvidado por completo. Iba a poner una solución con `display: inline-block` pero ahora que `flexbox` es soportado por todos los navegadores... Que le den a IE!!

Comment: Yo colocaba `display: inline-block` para ponerlas horizontal y luego usaba float para centrar las `li` y no podía.

Comment: @Camilo ¿te sirvió la respuesta?

Comment: Si, Gracias por tu ayuda @Shaz

Comment: Entonces puedes marcar esta respuesta como aceptada, con el ícono que está a la izquierda, cerca a donde está el 3.

Comment: Listo respuesta aceptada, @Shaz eres programador profesional o solo este es tu hobby?

Answer (score 1):

Revisa esta parte:

```css
.container {
 clear:both;
 float:left;
 overflow:hidden;
 width:100%;
}

#menu {
 float:left;
 left:50%;
 list-style-type:none;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0;
 position:relative;
}

#menu li {
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 right:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cointainer">
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a class="menu__link" href="#">Ejemplo</li></a>
            <li><a class="menu__link" href="#">Ejemplo</li></a>
            <li><a class="menu__link" href="#">Ejemplo</li></a>
            <li><a class="menu__link" href="#">Ejemplo</li></a>
            <li><a class="menu__link" href="#">Ejemplo</li></a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```